# Should i remove System.out.println statements in my android app

Tags: android, console

Will this sysouts affect my application performance?. I'm about to deploy this app and i have several sysout methods which i used for debuging purposes in my parsers. Is there a quick command for commenting all sysouts or a way to turn em all off without erasing'em or it doesn't matter to have'em on?

Comment: Comment them off manually...

Comment: Will do that. I was just curious about this.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a great idea to leave the logs as it is in your release since it can become the attack surface through which attacker can understand your app and exploit its vulnerabilities.

You can configure your proguard rules to do that. Place following config in your proguard rules:

```
-assumenosideeffects class java.io.PrintStream {
     public void println(%);
     public void println(**);
 }
```